# Code to exchange a string between C++ and objective-C++ and visa versa, is there a better way?

Tags: macos, objective-c++, utf-16

I have written code to exchange a string from c++ to objective-C++ and visa versa as follow:

```
// C++ UTF-16 string to objective-c++
std::u16string str = u"你好 سلام Hello Привет สวัสดีชาวโลก";
NSString *nsstr = [[NSString alloc] initWithCharacters:(const unichar*)str.data() length:str.length()];

// Objective-c++ UTF-16 string to C++  
NSData *data = [nsstr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
std::u16string bstr ([data length] / 2, 0);
[data getBytes:(char16_t*)bstr.c_str() length:[data length]];
```

**The previous code working without problems but I don't know whether there's another better way or not?**

Comment: It's not valid to cast away the `const` of `bstr.c_str()` and write into the buffer.

Comment: @KenThomases: `getBytes` method copies a number of bytes from the start of the data object into a specific buffer. So, the data in the buffer is just a copy, right?

Comment: The buffer pointed to by `bstr.c_str()` is not yours to write into. And there's no guarantee that writing into it will a) work without crashing, or b) change the value of `bstr` itself.